# What to use as css selector in protractor when writing a code

Tags: selenium, protractor

What to use in element(by.css("") for writing tests in protractor if the class am referring to is `<a class="button button-large button-secondary has-shield download-btn"`

```
  var HomePage = function() {
this.centerStageButtons = element(by.css(".text-center"));

this.tryTheAngular = this.centerStageButtons.all(by.css(".button.button-large.button-primary.has-shield.has-shadow")).get(0);
this.downloadButton = this.centerStageButtons.element(by.css("..button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download-btn"));

describe('angularjs.org', function() {
  var homePage = new HomePage();

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');
    });
    it('should have two buttons', function() {
      //expect(homePage.tryTheAngular.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
      expect(homePage.downloadButton.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);

  });
});
```

};

It is giving me a false positive as test is passed

Comment: I tried by.css(".button.button-large.button-secondary")

Comment: This is what am getting when I execute the test Started

----
No specs found
Finished in 0.004 seconds

[15:41:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:41:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Comment: if you fail to get it stating that no element was found, please provide the whole property of the anchor and if there is a unique text inside.

Comment: Are you expecting something on your code? it is passing based from your comment. Please post your code if you are expecting something else, what is being done on that element? e.g. clicked, checked the presence etc

Comment: @Paul Co I have added the code above. This gives me a false positive

Comment: You are saying in the comment above `No specs found Finished in 0.004 seconds [15:41:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running [15:41:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed `. If that is the false positive you mean, then you are not reading the log correct. It means that no specs has been found and no tests has been executed. Secondly you have `this.downloadButton = this.centerStageButtons.element(by.css("..button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download-btn"));`. There is a double `..` in your code. That will never find the element

Comment: I didn't notice the "No Spec Found", can you double check your config file? ensure that your specs filename is correctly mentioned on your config file.

Comment: @SUPARNASOMAN try  `("a.button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download-btn")`

Comment: @kushal tried that and getting the error ---- Started
[10:38:00] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .text-center) - the first result will be used
F

Failures:
1) angularjs.org should have two buttons
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .a.button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download‌​-btn)
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .a.button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download‌​-btn)
--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
this.downloadButton = element(by.css(".button.button-large.button-secondary.has-shield.download-btn"));
```